# IIS Webapi .NET 4.5 406 mime type error

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net

We have a .NET WEBAPI running on IIS 7.5 and it will run as designed for 1 to 2 weeks then the Web api site starts to give a

```
406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.
The page you are looking for cannot be opened by your browser because it has a file name extension that your browser does not accept.
```

The only thing that fixes it is to re-create the site using the same exact directory of code, but after another 1 - 2 weeks the same 406 error.  Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: When this happens, enable Failed request tracing in IIS for your site for status 406 to find out which MIME-Type causes this. Then try to figure out why your app would send such a MIME type.

Comment: Will try this on July 5th.  No changes to production before a 3 day weekend.   I will let you know the findings.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: Failed request tracing produces no results.  Same error - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moojjoo/images/master/mime406.png

Comment: So the failed request tracing logs have no mention of a 406?

Comment: Peter, we had to be sure we followed the following, --- https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests.   We had to configure the failure definition.  We are getting data now.  Thanks.